# How to create an entry from a different index, if it exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I create a large index of documents every day. What I'd like to start to do is create this index but re-use values from the previous day's index if they exist.

So let's say my index contains documents with a string key and an integer value.

I get a list of a bunch of keys with no values. The values are filled-in during the course of the day with updates. But if the key exists in the previous day, I'd like to copy the value over to start.

Short of writing code that does a lookup before creating my bulk inserts, is there a more efficient way to tell ElasticSearch, "Hey, if this key exists in the other index over here, use the value please?"

Answer (score 0):

My team uses memcached for something very similar to this.

Check memcached for the key before writing a value to Elasticsearch, if the key is in memcached then use it, otherwise write the new k/v pair to memcached (so it'll be there next time!) and continue. It's much more lightweight than doing a query with Elasticsearch. For your use case I suppose every time you got the update with the value for the key, you'd write that to memcached.